# How to specify that an argument of a method should have a specific interface

Tags: java, methods, interface, arguments

In java, how to specify that an argument of a method should have a specific interface or many specifics interfaces.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only specify one supertype for a particular argument.  If you can't do that, you have to add overloads of the method for each possibility.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html
`<T extends B1 & B2 & B3>`
A type variable with multiple bounds is a subtype of all the types listed in the bound. If one of the bounds is a class, it must be specified first. For example:

`class A { /* ... */ }

interface B { /* ... */ }

interface C { /* ... */ }

class D <T extends A & B & C> { /* ... */ }`

If bound A is not specified first, you get a compile-time error:

`class D <T extends B & A & C> { /* ... */ }`  // compile-time error

and in your method

`public String process(<T extends A & B & C> yourTypeVariable){
//TODO}